# Use interfaces to build graphql query

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo, apollo-angular

is it possible to build graphql queries using existing interfaces?
or we should write same code twice)

for example [in the doc we have](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/services/)

```
interface Post {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  ...
```

and then writing same fields in query

```
query allPosts {
      posts {
        id
        title
        ...
```

is there any way to write something like

```
query allPosts {
      posts: Post[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do something like that because TypeScript types don't exist at runtime. Interfaces are also insufficient to represent GraphQL fields because they can't capture information like argument values or directive usage.

You can, however, auto-generate TypeScript types from existing queries, which is what is normally done. See [GraphQL Code Generator](https://graphql-code-generator.com).

Answer (score 1):

NO ... `types!=queries` ... `posts: Post[]` already used in response definition

Query defines what subset (fields) you need from this (and other) type(-s), f.e. only title

You're probably looking for [Fragments](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/fragments/)

Comment: and why i cant make query from type? fields are the same
Fragments are not what i am looking for

Comment: get answer in second comment)